# timeZone issue for Expo Android

Tags: javascript, android, date, timezone, expo

Seems no matter what package I use, there seems to always be a problem with timeZone `RangeError: timeZone is not supported` with Expo(v40) Android. I tried adding a polyfill as mentioned in https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1377#issuecomment-775991702, but realized the comment also stated:

`"This code is only usable if you do not use "toLocaleString" anywhere, except dayjs. It just fix dayjs, but can break other code (if it use toLocaleString method)."`

I can't edit app `build.gradle` since I'm using expo so a little confused as to what I can do here. Has anyone come up with a solution?

Current setup:

```
"expo": "~40.0.0",
"expo-localization": "^10.2.0",
"date-fns": "^2.21.3",
"date-fns-tz": "^1.1.4",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
```

Comment: The pollyfill looks like a really bad idea as it replaces the built–in *toLocaleString* method. You need to show the code that produces the error and how you're specifying *timeZone*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems like I found the solution. I used this polyfill https://github.com/formatjs/date-time-format-timezone and got rid of `intl` package. Now date-fns-tz works for both android and ios